# Insert multiple row to table in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I added one thousand rows to one of my tables while working on SQL Server, I used something like:

```
DECLARE @cnt2 INT = 0;
WHILE @cnt2 < 1000
BEGIN
    insert into [MyDB].[dbo].[Table] (ID, LastName, FirstName, StreetAddress, City, ZipCode, PhoneNumber, Email, EnteringDate, GroupID)
    values (00+ Convert(varchar(5), @cnt2), 'StudentLastName-' + Convert(varchar(5), @cnt2), 'FirstName', 'Street',  'City', 'xx-xxx', '500-000-000', 'email@student.xyz', GETDATE(), 0, 1)
    SET @cnt2 = @cnt2 + 1;
END;
```

And it works correctly, but I must have similar code to insert values during using PostgreSQL (I'm working with pgadmin).

Could you help me with this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, `generate_series()` comes handy for this kind of task, since it avoids the need for a loop.

Consider:

```
insert into mytable (
    ID, 
    LastName, 
    FirstName, 
    StreetAddress, 
    City, 
    ZipCode, 
    PhoneNumber, 
    Email, 
    EnteringDate, 
    GroupID
)
select 
    n, 
    'StudentLastName-' || n::text,
    'FirstName', 
    'Street',  
    'City', 
    'xx-xxx', 
    '500-000-000', 
    'email@student.xyz', 
    now(), 
    0, 
    1
from generate_series(0, 999) as t(n)
```